# Facebook like button should ignor subdomain

Tags: c#, facebook

I implemented a Facebook like button

Desktop website

```
 <fb:like  href="www.example.com/singer/eminem" data-colorscheme="dark"
  send="true" width="80px" show_faces="true"> </fb:like>
```

Mobile website

```
<fb:like  href="www.m.example.com/singer/eminem" data-colorscheme="dark"
 send="true" width="80px" show_faces="true"> </fb:like>
```

Both url  `www.example.com/singer/eminem` and subdomain `www.m.example.com/singer/eminem` gives the same data, so i want facebook like button to ignore the subdomain and give single button like button to both the URLs. Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik this is not possible. For Facebook it´s a different Link and highly doubt that you can combine them.

All you can do is use the default domain for both and redirect to mobile with JavaScript. That would be better anyway, because after all you don´t want the mobile URL to be posted on Facebook.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i did exactly it. I used same url for mobile and desktop website for facebook.